# Создание директории в существующей директории

Tags: python

Есть папка `person` в ней папка `age1`, как создать в папке `age1` папку, допустим `Gulag`?

Comment: `pathlib.Path('/person/age1/Gulag').mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)`

Comment: @Akina Не создаёт, в моём случае, я ввожу имя директории сам. Получается вот такое `pathlib.Path('/person/age1/{0}'.format(name1)).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)`

Comment: @Akina и ничего не создаётся, Папка person и age1 уже созданы, надо чтобы там создалась папка

Comment: Библиотеку импортировать не забыли? и укажите точную версию питона.

Comment: @Akina Библиотека импортирована `import pathlib`, Версия 3.7

Comment: *в моём случае, я ввожу имя директории сам.* А если всё же использовать литерал - создаётся? или тоже - ни папки, ни ошибки?

Comment: @Akina Нет, используя литерал не создаётся.

Comment: Тогда проверьте и при необходимости нормализуйте путь. Ибо [документация](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) полагает, что при верных параметрах должно срабатывать правильно.

Answer (score 7):

Используйте `os.makedirs`. С ним можно указать целый путь из папок, которые затем будут созданы:

```python
import os

name1 = 'Gulag'

os.makedirs('person/age1/{}'.format(name1), exist_ok=True)
```

Comment: Зачем мне создавать паки, которые уже созданы?

Comment: У меня папки `person` и `age1` созданы мне нужно создать папку с ведённым мной именем в папке `age1` которая располагается в папке `person`

Comment: Это работает как `mkdir -p`. Если директория существует, то создает следующую в пути, если нет создает ее и в ней создает следующую

Comment: Если указан параметр `exist_ok=True`, то `makedirs` не создаёт папки, которые уже существуют. Вместо этого он использует этот путь для создания папок по нему.

Comment: Папка Gulag не создаётся

Comment: Проверьте права на запись в директорию, где пытаетесь создать папку. Она не может не создаваться. Код рабочий

Comment: @МаксимХалин А эта папка случайно не скрыта? Попробуйте убрать параметр `exist_ok=True`, будет ли какая-нибудь ошибка?

Comment: @Jazzis Папка не скрыта, убрал, вот такая ошибка `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Tom/Desktop/tests/test.py", line 20, in <module>
    os.makedirs('person/age1/{}'.format(name1))
  File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\os.py", line 221, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Невозможно создать файл, так как он уже существует: 'person/age1/Gulag'`

Comment: @Fisherman Как проверить права?

Comment: @МаксимХалин Судя по ошибке, папка уже создана.

Comment: @Jazzis Посмотрите https://i.imgur.com/KklUSWA.png

Comment: @МаксимХалин Попробуйте используя адресную строку перейти в папку `Gulag` (для уверенности).

Comment: @Jazzis нет такой папки, попробовал

Comment: @МаксимХалин А откуда вы запускаете скрипт? Если вы его запускаете не из папки `tests`, а из какой-то другой, то папки могут создаваться в ней. На всякий случай можно попробовать `print(os.path.abspath('person/age1/Gulag')` выполнить, чтобы узнать полный путь до этих папок.

Comment: @Jazzis У меня файл test.py Находиться в папке tests, Оттуда я его и запускаю.

Answer (score 1):

Во 2-м `makedirs` создаёт промежуточные каталоги без указания дополнительных параметров. Добавил проверку на существование создаваемого каталога:

```
import os

def create_folder(workspace, folder):
    path = os.path.join(workspace, folder)
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.makedirs(path)
        print "create folder with path {0}".format(path)
    else:
        print "folder exists {0}".format(path)

#create_folder("person/age1", "Gulag")
create_folder(r"C:\TEMP\person\age1", "Gulag")
# create folder with path C:\TEMP\person\age1\Gulag
```

Comment: раскоментировал строку `create_folder("person/age1", "Gulag")` Пишет, что папка существует, хотя её нет

Comment: скорей всего у вас запутано с относительными путями, используйте абсолютные